# IIS website upgrade

Tags: iis, wix, wix3.7

I'm building a website installer, during the installation phase I need to create an application pool and a website under IIS.

During the install / uninstall phases everything works fine: IIS is configured as expected.

Now I can't figure out how to obtain a decent user experience on upgrades: actually the setupkit overrides every configuration on the website (i.e. port bindings).

Is it possible to instruct Wix to not alter the website / application pool configuration during updates?

Here the code:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">      
  <Directory Id="INETPUB" Name="Inetpub">
  <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MyWebSite">
  <Component Id="MyWebSiteIssConfiguration" Guid="MY-GUID">
    <Condition><![CDATA[NOT Installed]]></Condition>

    <iis:WebAppPool Id="MyWebSiteAppPool"
                  Name="[APP_POOL_NAME]"
                  Identity="localService"
                  ManagedPipelineMode="Integrated"
                  ManagedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" />

    <iis:WebSite Id="MyWebSiteWebsite" Description='[WEB_SITE_NAME]' Directory='INSTALLFOLDER' AutoStart='yes' StartOnInstall='yes'>
      <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" Port="[WEB_SITE_PORT]" />
      <iis:WebApplication Id="MyWebSiteApplication" Name="[WEB_SITE_NAME][WEBSITE_ID]" WebAppPool="MyWebSiteAppPool"></iis:WebApplication>
      <iis:WebDirProperties Id="MyWebSiteWebDirProperties" AnonymousAccess="no" WindowsAuthentication="yes" />
    </iis:WebSite>

    <CreateFolder/>
  </Component>
</Directory>
</Directory>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I've found a workaround that fits my needs.

First of all I've marked the component containing the website configuration (`MyWebSiteIssConfiguration` in my sample code) as `Permanent='yes'`: this way the website is never uninstalled.

Also I've set `ConfigureIfExists='no'` on the website so during upgrade the configuration on the website is left untouched.